# Recursive code gives wrong answer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, backtracking

I want to print all subsets of an array using backtracking in Javascript my algorithm is right but it gives some unexpected answers.
I think this is related to javascript language.

```
// this is base function where i am calling recursive function .
function solveIt(A,B,C,D,E){
      let ans = [];   // this is ans array
      let sub = [];    // this is subset array 
      printAllSubset(A,0,sub,ans); // Calling the helper function
      return ans;    // returing anser
       
    
}
```

```
// My recursive code 
function printAllSubset(nums,idx,sub,ans){
    
    if(idx==nums.length){.   // This is base condition
        ans.push(sub);
       
        return ans;
        
    }
    // include current index
    sub.push(nums[idx]);            // including the current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);  // recuring for all possible sub problem
    
    // exclude current index
    
    sub.pop();                            // excluding the current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);   // recuring for all possible scenerio
     
    
}
```

```
const A=[1,2,3];
const res = solveIt(A,B,C);

console.log(res)

// output I am getting - 
[
  [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], []
]

// But the expected output should be - 

[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: You are adding to the sub array and removing it right the way, I'm not sure how this supposed to retain any data in it.

Comment: What is `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build towards having the answer in `ans` but then throw it away. One answer is to make `ans` a global variable and remove it from recursive function calls:

```
let ans=[]
function solveIt(A){ 
      printAllSubset(A,0,[]); // Calling the helper function
}

function printAllSubset(nums,idx,sub){

    if(idx===nums.length){.   // This is base condition
        ans.push(sub);
    }
    // include current index
    sub.push(nums[idx]);            // including the     current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub);  // recuring for all possible sub problem

    // exclude current index

    sub.pop();                            // excluding the current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub);   // recuring for all possible scenerio
}
```

The other is to catch the return of the recursive calls to `printAllSubset`:

```
function solveIt(A){ 
      return printAllSubset(A,0,[],[]); // Calling the helper function
}

function printAllSubset(nums,idx,sub,ans){

    if(idx===nums.length){.   // This is base condition
        ans.push(sub);
   
        return ans;
    
    }
    // include current index
    sub.push(nums[idx]);            // including the     current index
    ans=printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);  // recuring for all possible sub problem

    // exclude current index

    sub.pop();                            // excluding the current index
    ans=printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);   // recuring for all possible scenerio

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: None of your solutions are actually work...did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are adding the same `sub` array to `ans` and any changes to `sub` reflect inside `ans` data as well.
So you'll need add a copy of `sub` instead:

```js
const A=[1,2,3];
const res = solveIt(A);

console.log(res)

// this is base function where i am calling recursive function .
function solveIt(A,B,C,D,E){
      let ans = [];   // this is ans array
      let sub = [];    // this is subset array 
      printAllSubset(A,0,sub,ans); // Calling the helper function
      return ans;    // returing anser
       
    
}
// My recursive code 
function printAllSubset(nums,idx,sub,ans){
    
    if(idx==nums.length){   // This is base condition
        ans.push([...sub]); // push a copy of the array
       
        return ans;
        
    }
    // include current index
    sub.push(nums[idx]);            // including the current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);  // recuring for all possible sub problem
    
    // exclude current index
    
    sub.pop();                            // excluding the current index
    printAllSubset(nums,idx+1,sub,ans);   // recuring for all possible scenerio
     
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here show what was wrong with your code and how to fix it.  I would just like to demonstrate a cleaner recursive way to write this:

```js
const powerset = ([x, ...xs] = []) =>
  x == undefined
    ? [[]]
    : powerset (xs) .flatMap (ys => [ys, [x, ...ys]])

console .log (JSON .stringify (powerset ([1, 2, 3])))
```

As with all recursion, one useful way to think about this is to recognize that it works for a base case, and if every recursive call make progress toward a base case, and if we can see that when it works for our recursive call it also works for our current call, then we can be assured that it works for all cases.  Because `powerset ([]) //=> [[]]`, it works for a base case.  Because every recursive call involves shrinking our input array by one, then our second condition holds; we'll eventually reach a base case.  The third condition we show by example: we assume that `powerset ([2, 3])` properly yields `[[], [2], [3], [2, 3]]`, then `powerset ([1, 2, 3])` will yield

```js
[[], [2], [3], [2, 3]] .flatMap (ys => [ys, [1, ...ys]])
```

which is the same as

```js
[... [[], [1]], ... [[2], [1, 2]], ... [[3], [1, 3]], ... [[2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
//    `--[]--'      `----[2]----'       `----[3]----'     `------[2, 3]------'
```

which is simply

```js
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

and so the recursive case works properly.  It's not hard to actually prove that all the subsets will show up with this technique.  We would just formalize the example above.

But this means that this function will accurately capture the powerset of a set expressed as a JS array.