# Subsets leetcode - Pushing into arr seems to be incorrectly pushing into wrong indexes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Was working on this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/

and came up with this solution:

`INPUT = [1, 2, 3]`

```
var subsets = function(nums) {
    
    let ans = []
    
    for (let num of nums) {
        
        // DUPLICATE ARRAY
        ans = [...ans, ...ans]
        const size = ans.length
        
        // ITERATE THROUGH LAST HALF OF ARR
        for (let i = size / 2; i < size; i++) {
            ans[i].push(num) <------------- THIS AINT RIGHT :(
        }
        
        ans.push([num])
    }
    
    return [[], ...ans]
};

ANS = [[],[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3],[2,3],[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3],[2,3],[3]] (INCORRECT)
```

However, it seemed to be incorrectly pushing values in multiple indexes for some reason. After fiddling around with the code thinking my logic is correct, I came up with this:

```
var subsets = function(nums) {
    
    let ans = []
    
    for (let num of nums) {
        
        // DUPLICATE ARRAY
        ans = [...ans, ...ans]
        const size = ans.length
        
        for (let i = size / 2; i < size; i++) {
            ans[i] = [...ans[i], num] <--------------- THIS WORKS
        }
        
        ans.push([num])
    }
    
    return [[], ...ans]
};


ANS = [[],[1],[1,2],[2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]] (correct)
```

And that ended up working... Why is this happening? Doesn't `arr[i].push(num)` pretty much equal the same thing as `arr[i] = [...arr[i], num]`

Comment: I've temporarily deleted my answer, because we need to know your input (please include it in the question itself). And I was focusing on the question of why the `push` wasn't equivalent, not to answer the actual challenge :)

Comment: It doesnt work. That's why im so confused. `ans = [[0], [1], [2]]`. So duplicating it would be `ans = [[0], [1], [2], [0], [1], [2]]`. So when iterating through the second half, push should be pushing correctly... but it isnt...

Comment: The input is [1, 2, 3]

Comment: The input is `nums = [0, 1, 2]`. The desired output is `[[],[1],[1,2],[2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]`. You can see after each loop, i push `[num]` into the `ans` arr

Comment: @trincot The second algo i made does work. Im just more curious about why the first solution doesnt work since the line that I changed pretty much is the same thing but produces different results.

Comment: Yes, I see now what you are doing, @sssyn.

Comment: ah, yes, now I see too. interesting.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69440854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the subarrays are not copied when you do:

```
    ans = [...ans, ...ans]
```

This merely produces the *same* subarray references. This means that when you `push` unto one of the subarrays in the *second* half of `ans`, you'll see the effect also via the *first* half of `ans`, as both halves reference the *same* subarrays.

So to solve this, make a deeper copy when producing the second half:

```
    ans = [...ans, ...ans.map(arr => Array.from(arr))]
```

The second, working version, performs this deeper copy in the line that you marked.

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes sense. Dang array references... Thanks @trincot!